# in C++ "unhandled exception at 0x778215de in prject1.exe: 0xC0000005:Access violating writing location 0x00000016"

Tags: exception, unhandled

When I am debugging a project, gives me an error on the window

> unhandled exception at 0x778215de in prject1.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violating writing location 0x00000016

And in `mlock.c` shows me that code lines:

```
void __cdecl _unlock (
        int locknum
        )
{
        /*
         * leave the critical section.
         */
        LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are accessing your array out of its bounds... You should check if your array contains more than `22` items.

OR

You should check if the item is properly initialized at position `22`.

Comment: Thx for ur answer, but how to undestand an array contains more that 22? And why 22? And my arrays haven't overloading. Have u any idea?

Comment: You are trying to write to a location `0x16`, which is 22 in decimal system. Anyway you are writing to an index in your array that is not properly initialized.

Comment: Yes, of course. The program gives me like this error: [link](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/2428/1a68456c64bf2b02219b5f1.jpg)

Comment: What is `_locktable[]` by the way? How is it defined?

Comment: I don't know. I beginner of that sphere.

Comment: The mlock.c file is automatically created. And It said that is "Multi-thread locking routines"

Comment: Is this project available online? Sounds like tough stuff, multi-threading is quite difficult.

Comment: No, it isn't available online. it's written by myself. I wrote that code from a book

Comment: Sorry, but if you have no serious clue what you are doing, it is hard to help you...

Comment: I generally understood meaning of the code. But I can't understand, which that code from a book, so why it's invalid

Comment: then please post all of your code or link it to pastebin or anything

Comment: I'm converting all comments from my language to english. It's take over 30-40 minuts

Comment: Do u have a mail to send files?

Comment: I have more SLOC. I have two files: a header and a cpp files.